# React Native - Why we use WebView.extraNativeComponentConfig() in WebView component?

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native

There is no [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/webview#extranativecomponentconfig) for this method in the official website of `react native`. Can anyone tell why we use `WebView.extraNativeComponentConfig()` in `WebView` component? A little example will be more appreciated. Thanks !!!